# ERROR Unexpected git bash argument format

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio has been crashing a lot for me over the past few weeks (Windows 10). Here's the error that shows up in the logs:

> 17 Nov 2015 07:42:28 [rsession-Michael] ERROR Unexpected git bash argument format: --login -i; LOGGED FROM: HRESULT rstudio::session::modules::git::{anonymous}::detectGitBinDirFromShortcut(rstudio::core::FilePath*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionGit.cpp:2378

It *seems* to happen when I call `qplot`, but I can't figure out a pattern. For example:

```
# This works...
qplot(data = birthdays, x = dob_day) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:31) +
    facet_wrap(~dob_month, ncol=3)

# This usually (not always) crashes:
qplot(data = birthdays, x = dob_month) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:12) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:11)
```

This is just one example. Sometimes a plot will stop working by adding a `binwidth` value, or some seemingly innocent change.

I found the code below to reinstall all packages: it seemed to run successfully, but made no difference:

```
lib <- .libPaths()[1]
package_df <- as.data.frame(installed.packages(lib))
package_list <- as.character(package_df$Package)
install.packages(package_list)
```

It doesn't seem to be my code, as it runs fine on another installation. Any suggestions where to go from here?

Comment: You can go to the RStudio support: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for the link, checking it out now. There doesn't seem to be much info on this specific error, but I'll keep looking...

Comment: You also can report the problem, I guess.